# in sublime text, is there a way to specify a file type in the file

Tags: sublimetext

Is there a way to add a line at the beginning of the file to specify the file type such as the following in emacs or vi:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
```

I would like to be able to set the format of some files that dont have file extensions such as Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 3):

In Sublime there is a way to apply syntax highlighting by the file extension. To perform this:

```
View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as... > [TheSyntaxYouWant]
```

For the case where you don't have a file extension, you can use some of these plugins that behave like VI or EMACS:

[Sublime Modelines](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Modelines)

[Emacs-like Sublime Modeline](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emacs-like%20Modelines)

You can also use [ApplySintax](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ApplySyntax), but it necessitate to perform some configurations before you can really use it.

Comment: This text explain well how to resolve the problem : [Vagrantfile Syntax Highlighting in Sublime Text](https://medium.com/@iturgeon/vagrantfile-syntax-highlighting-in-sublime-text-92bb72a74361)

Answer (score 0):

Try this two plugins, together they can parse the modelines correctly:

- [Emacs-like Modelines](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emacs-like%20Modelines)
- [Vim​Modelines](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/VimModelines)  * this do not support `ft` attr